# Swift EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION on call to typealias / typed / defined closure w/o compiler error or warning

Tags: swift, compiler-bug

Given a struct, a class, and typed closure:

```
struct Vector3d {
    var X:Double
    var Y:Double
    var Z:Double
}

class Sprite {

    var mass: Double = 0.0

    init(mass: Double) {
        self.mass = mass
    }
}

typealias ForceComputation =
    (NSTimeInterval, Sprite) -> Vector3d?
```

The following code crashes with `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION`:

```
// Construct an instance of the class to call back with
var ball = Sprite(mass: 3.0)

// Create an instance of closure
var gravity:ForceComputation = { (projectile:Sprite) -> Vector3d in
    // use this line to close ball so it's available in debugger
    var mass1 = ball.mass

    // use mass1 in following line to ensure not optimized out
    // (ignore invalid gravity formula)
    var verticleAcceleration = -9.8 * projectile.mass * mass1

    return Vector3d(X:0.0, Y:verticleAcceleration, Z:0.0)
}

// activate the closure
gravity(ball)
```

The debugger shows two different values for `projectile` and `ball`. The field `mass` in `projectile` is invalid. However `mass` is valid for `ball` both inside and outside the closure. There are no compiler errors or warnings but `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION` is thrown when `projectile.mass` is executed?

Despite the misleading debug data, the problem has nothing to do with the parameter to the `ForceComputation` closure. The problem is the returned struct is defined as optional in the `typealias`:

```
typealias ForceComputation =
    (Sprite) -> Vector3d?
```

but constructed with a non-optional return type (note the lack of a `?` after `Vector3d`):

```
// Create an instance of closure
var gravity:ForceComputation = { (projectile:Sprite) -> Vector3d in
    ....
}
```

Changing the above code to remove the typing:

```
// Create an instance of closure
var gravity = { (projectile:Sprite) -> Vector3d in
    ....
}
```

will fix the code or ensuring that the return type is optional (note `?` after `Vector3d`):

```
// Create an instance of closure
var gravity:ForceComputation = { (projectile:Sprite) -> Vector3d? in
    ....
}
```

will also make this work. My question is if this is a compiler bug and should be reported to Apple or is there a reason the `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION` throwing code should compile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a compiler bug (confirmed via Twitter [here](https://twitter.com/joshcodes/status/562308267083595777)) but there are already a number of known issues around optional-ness to returns with Swift.

Comment: It could well be a compiler bug, but the code in your question isn’t valid (possibly cut/paste error?) – `var gravity: ForceComputation = { (projectile:Sprite) -> Vector3d in` has an argument arity mismatch...

Comment: ah, it looks you typealised ForceComputation a second time

Comment: ForceComputation was not aliased a second time. The later code is snippets of modifications to the original code. Given the way if failed, the code should not have compiled, or at least should have had a warning, for the argument arity mismatch.